# javascript - identifying and quantifying consecutively looped elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of many items.  the way I have designed the logic, only identical items may be adjacent to each other in the array. For example, "one, one, one, two, two, three, three, three" - the program doesn't allow "one, two, one, one".

how do i create a loop that returns an array of the name, and how many times it occurs consecutively? Example - "one,one,one,two,two,three" should create [one,3],[two,2],[three,1].

i hope the question is clear and thanks for he help.

an example of many failed attempts...

```
for (var i=0; i<fieldcount; i++){
        var thisgroup;
        var loops = fieldcount-1;
        if (i==0){
            thisgroup = jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i].group;
        } else if (i>0 && jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i].group == thisgroup){
            groupcount= groupcount+1;
        }else if (i<loops && jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i+1] != thisgroup){
            groups.push(thisgroup, groupcount);
            thisgroup = jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i+1].group;
            groupcount = 1;
        }else if (i==loops){
            groups.push(thisgroup, groupcount);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: do you mean  [one,3],[two,2],[three,1] these are three arrays right ?

Comment: yes jfriens, a hundred things in three nights - all variations of nested for loops. sometimes very close, but but never quite getting there.

Comment: i just edited the post with my latest attempt - of course, this is not a nested loop.  but perhaps the closest ive come.

Comment: What output does this give you as of now, @user3614570 ?

Comment: the behavior is bizarre.  if i enter a value for group, i would get [a,1]. a second value will return [a,2], but for some reason a third value will return []. this with 4 total elements. it looks like it will work until the field before the last.  if there are 6 elements, it will work until i enter the fifth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only care for consecutive items, a simple loop will do it:

```
var items = ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three'],
    result = [];

for (var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; ) {
    var current = [items[i], 1];
    result.push(current);
    while (++i<l && current[0] == items[i])
        current[1]++;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Bergi,  this worked perfectly.  Nice and simple too - i tend to over think some of these procedures and try to get too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the list is already sorted, you can simply iterate over it:

```
var items = ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three'],
prev,
current,
result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (current !== null && prev === items[i]) {
        result[current][1]++; // increase count
    } else {
        result[current = result.length] = [items[i], 1]; // new item
    }
    prev = items[i]; // track previous item for next loop
}

console.log(result);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/tiwahire/1/watch?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach` to provide a function to perform the counting on each element. Simply store the results in a new value:

```
// sample data
var list = [
    {'name':'one'},
    {'name':'one'},
    {'name':'two'},
    {'name':'two'},
    {'name':'two'},
    {'name':'three'},
    {'name':'three'},
];
// container for results
var counts = {};
list.forEach(function (item) {
    if (typeof counts[item.name] === 'undefined')
        counts[item.name] = 0;
    counts[item.name]++;
});

console.log(counts);
// output: Object { one=2, two=3, three=2}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Umuw9/

You mentioned wanting output as an array, eg `[['one',2],['two',3],['three',2]]`, you can use `for...in` for that:

```
var output = [];
for( var i in counts) {
    if (counts.hasOwnProperty(i)){
       output.push([i,counts[i]]);
    }
}
console.log(output);
// output: [["one", 2], ["two", 3], ["three", 2]]
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Dg6Cp/

... not knowing your use case, this looks like an unusual step.

**Documentation**

- `Array.forEach` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
- `for...in`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
- `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Why are you using `.map`? You should either use `forEach` or `reduce`.

Comment: @Bergi Eh, same difference. I started out playing with `map`, wound up not needing it. I updated the answer, but do you know of some performance reason not to use `map`, considering it accomplishes the same goal?

Comment: The goal of `.map` is to build an array. The goal of `.forEach` is to execute side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate unique list elements and count how many times each appears in list:

```
//
var quantify = function (array) {
  return array.
    // get unique elements
    filter(function (node, idx, array) {
      return idx === array.indexOf(node);
    }).
    // count how many times each appears in a list
    map(function (node) {
      for (
        var qty = 0, a = array, idx = a.indexOf(node);
        -1 !== idx; qty++, idx = a.indexOf(node, idx + 1)
      );
      return [node, qty];
    });
};
// eof
```